# How to import jquery plugin from master page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I´m using a jQuery plugin to validate only numbers in my website (I don´t wanna use "Type=number" and "TextMode") so I downloaded a plugin called **NumericInput.js** but when I try to used It doesn´t work
Here is the code that how I use:

My principal page

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/RecursosHumanos/MPRecursosHumanos.master" 
     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RegistroRecursos.aspx.cs" 
     Inherits="RecursosHumanos_RegistroRecursos" %>

     <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
     </asp:Content>
     <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentplaceHolder1" runat="Server">
     <!--INICIO CABECERA-->
     <div runat="server" class="container-fluid text-center letracabecera" id="cabecera">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="/../Imagenes/Sistegral.jpg" class="img-rounded imagenescab" alt="Sistegral" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2><b>ADMINISTRACION DE RECURSOS</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="/../Imagenes/Gmg.png" class="img-rounded imagenescab" alt="GMG" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default letra" id="panelDatosEmpleado">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                         <label class="control-label" for="txtRegRecIMSS">
                             <span class="form-text">Numero de IMSS:</span>
                         </label>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegRecIMSS" runat="server" CssClass="form-control ns_" MaxLength="10" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" placeHolder="IMSS del recurso"></asp:TextBox>
                     </div>
                     </div>
                   ...
```

This is my master page:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MPRecursosHumanos.master.cs" Inherits="RecursosHumanos_MPRecursosHumanos" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Consultores TI</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--REFERENCIAS PARA DISEÑO-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="/../Styles/css/CentrarTextoDiv.css"/>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src = "<%=  ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap/js/numericInput.js") %>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src = "<%= 
    ResolveClientUrl("~/Styles/bootstrap/js/numericInput.min.js") %>"></script>

   <!--REFERENCIAS PARA EL CALENDARIO--> 
   <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"> 
   </script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#txtRegRecIMSS").numericInput();
    });
</script>
```

The last function is where I use to validate the field but it doesnt work
How should I do the import of js file to make it work?

Comment: Check the source view (press Ctrl+U in the browser). Find the script tag and click the underlined `src`. Does that lead to the script file? Also, you're including both jQuery 3.3.1 and 2.1.1; not a good idea.

Comment: try using your script function in your webform rather than master page ! or try checking your path to the script as mentioned in comment above .

Comment: I tried the both but it doesn´t work also I removed one of jQuery including but not working :(